# Configure atomikos for hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

How can i configure Atomikos for HazelCast instance.As per the mastering-hazel cast we can only do it in java.How can i configure like i do for databases.If configuring is java is the way,then how i can make use of TransactionalTask to remove the boilerplate code starting and committing the transactions.i have tried like

```
public void insertIntoGridJTA( final List<String> list)
            throws NotSupportedException, SystemException,
            IllegalStateException, RollbackException {
        HazelcastInstance hazelcast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        HazelcastXAResource xaResource = hazelcast.getXAResource();
        TransactionContext context = xaResource.getTransactionContext();
        hazelcast.executeTransaction(new  TransactionalTask<Object>() {
        public Object execute(TransactionalTaskContext context)
                    throws TransactionException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TransactionalMap<Integer, String> map = context.getMap("demo");
            System.out.println("map"+map.getName());
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                map.put(i, list.get(i));
            }
                return null;
        }
        });
    }
```

But the transaction is not starting if i am using TransactionalTask

Answer (score 0):

Did you had a look at the Atomikos example in our examples repo? https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/transactions/xa-transactions/src/main/java/XATransaction.java

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @noctarius, I have done it like this in the past

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@Autowired
private HazelcastXAResource hzXAResource;
@Autowired
private UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager;

@Transactional
public void insert() throws SystemException, RollbackException {
    final Transaction transaction = userTransactionManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.enlistResource(hzXAResource);
    final TransactionContext hzTransactionContext = hzXAResource.getTransactionContext();
    final TransactionalMap<Long, String> hzCustomerMap = hzTransactionContext.getMap("hzCustomerMap");

    // Use a Java 8 stream to print out each tuple of the list
    CUSTOMERS_TEST_DATA.forEach(customer -> {
        log.info("Inserting customer record for {}", customer);
        hzCustomerMap.put(customer.getId(), customer.toString());
    });
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(Sql.SQL_INSERT.getSql(), new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
            ps.setString(1, CUSTOMERS_TEST_DATA.get(i).getFirstName());
            ps.setString(2, CUSTOMERS_TEST_DATA.get(i).getLastName());
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return CUSTOMERS_TEST_DATA.size();
        }
    });

    // Uncomment this to test the failure of the transaction
    //        hzCustomerMap.values((Predicate) entry -> {
    //            throw new RuntimeException();
    //        });

    transaction.delistResource(hzXAResource, XAResource.TMSUCCESS);
}
```